# How to tell if current thread is impersonating?

Tags: c++, security, winapi

I have a c++ application in which threads could impersonate using LogonUser/ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, and then revert impersonation using RevertToSelf. I ran across the bug which caused thread to impersonate this way twice. I want to prevent this by testing if current thread is already impersonating and throw exception if it is. Is there a way to tell if current thread is impersonating already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use OpenThreadToken.  If a thread has a token then it is impersonating; if it doesn't have a token then it is not impersonating.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer to the q as asked - personally, I would still prefer not to guess about this.

Comment: thanks, let me test that and then I'll mark it as correct if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

I expect you could do this using a convoluted sequence of Win32 API calls similar to [these checks for thread running as Administrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff420334.aspx).

However, it is far simpler (and better design) to ensure that impersonating threads always revert.  You could brute force this using the Win32 APIs, but I believe you could also do this by creating a wrapper class that impersonates on construction and reverts when it goes out of scope, similar to the common lock guard model for exception-safe mutex/critical section handling.  Even if you have more than a few places where your code does this, aligning them all on a reliable construct seems advisable.

Flow would then be:

```
{
  MyImpersonationClass newContext(desiredUser);  
      // constructor calls Impersonate, saving required info

  // do the code that requires impersonation here
}

// newContext goes out of scope, destructor calls RevertToSelf
```

Comment: problem is that /*do the code that requires impersonation here*/ might be calling some code that attempts to impersonate and I want to block this behavior

Comment: @galets - have your constructor save something in TLS (thread-local storage) to prevent recursive impersonation.  Destructor should reset this, of course.