# Getting the Current username when impersonated

Tags: c#, .net

I am using something like the following method to impersonate a user in my code:

[How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net)

In another class, I need to find out the current user (like "mydomain\moose"), but I won't have any idea if I'm currently impersonating another user or not.

How do I get the username, if I'm impersonating someone?

System.Environment.UserName and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name both return the original user, not the currently impersonated user.

More Details:

I am doing this impersonation so that I can access some files in a netowrk share the user usually does not have access to.

If I use a logon type of LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, I do see the new user, but I cannot access the network share. If I use a logon type of LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS (a value of 9), i can access the network share but I don't see the new user in Environment.UserName.

Comment: It should be returning the impersonated user.  Are you absolutely sure you are impersonated in the method call that you look up the current user.?

Comment: I just tested using the impersonated user to access a directory my logged on user does not have access to. I can access the directory, but both methods still return the original user. once I stop impersonation, I get access denied try to access the directory, so I know it's impersonating correctly.

Comment: Added more details. Seems to be the logon type causing the issue.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx.  You may want to try `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH`.  For NEW_CREDENTIALS it doesn't work because "The new logon session has the same local identifier but uses different credentials for other network connections."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out what the property `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` will return
if you use `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` or `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` as logon type for the LogonUser (inside the impersonation class) function:

1. Using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`

   ```
   // Assuming this code runs under USER_B

   using (var imp = new Impersonation("treyresearch", "USER_A", "SecurePwd", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ))
   {
     // Now, we run under USER_A
     Console.Out.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name); // Will return USER_A
   }
   ```
2. Using `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS`

   ```
   // Assuming this codes runs under USER_B

   using (var imp = new Impersonation("treyresearch", "USER_A", "SecurePwd", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS ))
   {
     Console.Out.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name); // Will return USER_B
   }
   ```

This is the behaviour as you have described in your question and is consistent with the description on MSDN for the `LogonUser` function. For `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` the created user token is just a clone of the current user token. This means that the created user session has the same identifier as the calling thread. The passed credentials to the `LogonUser` function are only used for outbound network connections.

Second, let me point out two situation where the described difference between `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` and `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` becomes clear:

- Two domain joined computers: computer_A, computer_B
- Two users: user_A (local admin on computer_A), user_B (only standard user rights on B)
- One networkshare on computer_B (mynetworkshare, user_B does have permission to access share).
- One local folder on computer_A (only user_A has permission to write to this folder).

You run your program on computer_A (under the account of user_A). You impersonate user_B (using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`). Then you connect to the network share on computer_B and try to copy a file to the local folder (only user_A has the permission to write to this folder). Then, you get an access denied error message, because the file operation is done with the permissions of user_B who does not have permission on the local folder.

Same situation as above. But now, we use `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` to impersonate user_B. We connect to the network drive and copy a file from the network drive to the local folder. In this case the operation succeeds because the file operation is done with the permissions of user_A.

Comment: This does help.  Unfortunately, the only method that gets me access to the network share I need is by using LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, but then I can't see who I am. So, I am going to need to try to not use impersonation in this particular case, which I think is the real solution anyway.  I'm marking this one as the answer because it has the most detail about the differences in the Logon type passed to LogonUser().

Comment: @Moose: If you just need to know wether or not you are impersonating then have a look a the following stackoverflow question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973982/how-to-tell-if-current-thread-is-impersonating

Comment: I just needed to know how to get the users identity and this gave me exactly what I was looking for.  AWESOME!

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT explanation of how LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

According to example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx the current identity changes during impersonation. Are you sure your code is inside the impersonated code block?

Comment: Yes, just tested. Still no luck. I know I'm getting the impersonation right, but it's still bringing back the original user.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a helper class that does it:

```
public static class ImpersonationUtils
{
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
    private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
    private const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
    private const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    private const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    private const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS =
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
        TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
        TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
        TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
        TOKEN_QUERY |
        TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    private enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
        IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        int dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
        IntPtr hExistingToken,
        int dwDesiredAccess,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        int ImpersonationLevel,
        int dwTokenType,
        ref IntPtr phNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr ProcessHandle,
        int DesiredAccess,
        ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
            ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            IntPtr hToken,
            bool bInherit);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
            IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr hObject);

    private static void LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock, int sessionId)
    {
        var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        var saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saProcess.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
        saThread.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

        var si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default";
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
            token,
            null,
            cmdLine,
            ref saProcess,
            ref saThread,
            false,
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
            envBlock,
            null,
            ref si,
            out pi))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateProcessAsUser failed");
        }
    }

    private static IDisposable Impersonate(IntPtr token)
    {
        var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
        return identity.Impersonate();
    }

    private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(Process process)
    {
        var token = IntPtr.Zero;
        var primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token))
        {
            var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
                token,
                TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                ref sa,
                (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                ref primaryToken))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DuplicateTokenEx failed");
            }

            CloseHandle(token);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "OpenProcessToken failed");
        }

        return primaryToken;
    }

    private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
    {
        var envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateEnvironmentBlock failed");
        }
        return envBlock;
    }

    public static void LaunchAsCurrentUser(string cmdLine)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
                if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    LaunchProcessAsUser(cmdLine, token, envBlock, process.SessionId);
                    if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock))
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DestroyEnvironmentBlock failed");
                    }
                }

                CloseHandle(token);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable ImpersonateCurrentUser()
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return Impersonate(token);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not find explorer.exe");
    }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
ImpersonationUtils.LaunchAsCurrentUser("notepad");

using (ImpersonationUtils.ImpersonateCurrentUser())
{

}
```

More explanations and examples you can find here :

[Impersonating CurrentUser from SYSTEM](http://amiryonatan.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/impersonating-currentuser_26.html)

Comment: I wish I found this months ago! too late I had to figure it out myself. 
Nonetheless, I think the OP is asking something else. He wants to determine the username string, even if the code is impersonating someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`QueryCredentialsAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379342.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean GetTokenInformation?
Not sure it is even possible to get a CredHandle to feed to QueryCredentialAttributes given an impersonation token HANDLE returned from LogonUser.