# How do I get files on a server in a different domain with a different user (Impersonation)?

Tags: c#, impersonation, credentials, getfiles

so what I'm trying to do is to list information such as the names of files according to a folder path given by the user. And as it is possible to target a file server which is in a different domain, you would need to use a different user.

I use `Directory.GetFiles(path)` to get the files. So is there a simple or not too hard way to accomplish that?

P.S. I do all that in a simple c# console application.

**[Edit]**

All I could find is this: [Getting the Current username when impersonated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613468/getting-the-current-username-when-impersonated)

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share

Comment: Possible duplicate: Accessing Password Protected Network Drives in Windows in C#? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563724/accessing-password-protected-network-drives-in-windows-in-c)